# APT tries to install previously failed installation

Tags: apt, kubuntu

I tried to install JDK but this failed beacuse it was already installed. From this point onwards, every time I install any application, apt tries to reinstall JDK afterwards.

Refer the following screenshot for when I installed Skype for Linux.

Apt first installs Skype (as expected) and then retries to install JDK. How can I stop the latter?

[image]

Comment: please remove the pixs and copy/paste what is in there into the questions. Easier to read and others can find the messages when searching

Answer (score 3):

The package `oracle-java8-installer` is partially installed, so Apt will constantly try to complete the installation. To stop it, you can completely remove the package with `sudo apt remove oracle-java8-installer`.

Comment: I see, removed the installer as suggested. I'll accept the answer once I verify the issue is resolved